# Haskell Program Out of Memory (Infinite Recursion? Loop? Something?)

Tags: haskell, infinite

**EDIT: Updated to include entire code.**

I'm pretty new to Haskell, and am having an issue with a program I've written to do some entropy calculations for a course assignment (the assignment is the calculations, the use of Haskell is a choice, so I'm not asking for someone to do my homework for me, it would have taken me a trivial amount of time and effort to do this in Python). The code takes a 1D array:

```
--- first input (length 2): 
---     0,0   0,1   1,0   1,1
---    [.48,  .02,  .02,  .48]
--- or:
---     0    1   
---    .48  .02  0
---               
---    .02  .48  1
```

I then have defined a couple of general functions:

```
log2 :: Float -> Float
log2 x =
  logBase 2 x

entropy :: [Float] -> Float
entropy probArray =
  sum(map (\i -> (i * (log2 (1/i)))) probArray)
```

As well as functions for each specific calculation:

```
-- calculate joint entropy
jointEntropy :: [Float] -> Float
jointEntropy probArray =
  entropy probArray

-- calculate entropy of X
splitByCol :: Int -> [Float] -> [[Float]]
splitByCol length probArray =
  [(take length probArray)] ++ (splitByCol length (drop length probArray))

xEntropy :: Int -> [Float] -> Float
xEntropy length probArray =
  entropy (map sum (splitByCol length probArray))

-- calculate entropy of Y
ithElements :: Int -> Int -> [Float] -> [Float]
ithElements level length matrixArray =
  let indexArray = zip [0..(length^2 - 1)] matrixArray
  in [snd x | x <- indexArray, fst x `mod` length == level]

splitByRow :: Int -> Int -> [[Float]] -> [[Float]]
splitByRow level length lists =
  if level == length
  then
    tail lists -- return list sans full matrix array which was being carried at the front
  else
    splitByRow (level+1) length (lists ++ [(ithElements level length (lists !! 0))]) 

yEntropy :: Int -> [Float] -> Float
yEntropy length probArray =
  entropy (map sum (splitByRow 0 length [probArray]))

--calculate mutual information
mutualInfo :: Float -> Float -> Float
mutualInfo xEnt yEnt =
  xEnt - yEnt

-- calculate conditional of X given Y - (X|Y)
xCond :: Float -> Float -> Float
xCond xEnt mInfo =
  xEnt - mInfo

-- calculate conditional of Y given X - (Y|X)
yCond :: Float -> Float -> Float
yCond yEnt mInfo =
  yEnt - mInfo
```

These are then all chained together to return an array with each of the calculations I've wanted to perform:

```
-- caller functions -> resArray ends up looking like [H(X,Y), H(X), H(Y), I(X;Y), H(X|Y), H(Y|X)]
calcJointEnt :: [Float] -> [Float]
calcJointEnt probArray =
  calcVarEnt probArray [(jointEntropy probArray)]

calcVarEnt :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
calcVarEnt probArray resArray =
  let len = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral (length probArray)))
  in calcMutual probArray (resArray ++ [(xEntropy len probArray), (yEntropy len probArray)])

calcMutual :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
calcMutual probArray resArray =
  calcCond probArray (resArray ++ [(mutualInfo (resArray !! 1) (resArray !! 2))])

calcCond :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
calcCond probArray resArray =
  resArray ++ [(xCond (resArray !! 1) (resArray !! 3)), (yCond (resArray !! 2) (resArray !! 3))]
```

And so on...I then have some functions to format a print string, and a main function to bring it all together:

```
-- prepare printout
statString :: (String, String) -> String
statString t =  
  (fst t) ++ ": " ++ (snd t)

printOut :: [Float] -> String
printOut resArray =
  let statArray = zip ["H(X,Y)", "H(X)", "H(Y)", "H(X;Y)", "H(X|Y)", "H(Y|X)"] (map show resArray)
  in "results:\n\t" ++ intercalate "\n\t" (map statString statArray) ++ "\n\n---\n"

-- main
main :: IO()
main = 
  let inputs = [[0.48,  0.02,  0.02,  0.48], [0.31,  0.02,  0.00,  0.02,  0.32,  0.02,  0.00,  0.02,  0.29]]
  in putStrLn (intercalate "" (map printOut (map calcJointEnt inputs)))
```

So I'm sure there are better ways to do a lot of this, but it seems to me from my minimal haskell experience and my slightly more expansive but still limited functional-esqe style programming experience that it should work.

My problem is that when I compile and run, I get this output:

```
bash-4.2$ ./noise 
results:
    H(X,Y): 1.2422923
noise: out of memory (requested 1048576 bytes)
```

With a large amount of time between the one result being printed out and the memory error message. When I pop it open in the ghci debugger (which I'm using for the first time), if I attempt to force, say, resArray in the printOut function, it does the same, and when I try to sequentially unpack resArray at the lowest level of the chaining functions:

```
calcCond :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]
calcCond probArray resArray =
  resArray ++ [(xCond (resArray !! 1) (resArray !! 3)), (yCond (resArray !! 2) (resArray !! 3))]
```

I get the following:

```
[noise.hs:101:3-96] *Main> seq _t1 ()
()
[noise.hs:101:3-96] *Main> :print resArray
resArray = (_t2::Float) : (_t3::[Float])
[noise.hs:101:3-96] *Main> seq _t2 ()
()
[noise.hs:101:3-96] *Main> :print resArray
resArray = 1.2422923 : (_t4::[Float])
[noise.hs:101:3-96] *Main> seq _t3 ()
()
[noise.hs:101:3-96] *Main> :print resArray
resArray = 1.2422923 : (_t5::Float) : (_t6::[Float])
[noise.hs:101:3-96] *Main> seq _t5 ()
^C^C^C^C^CInterrupted.
[noise.hs:101:3-96] *Main>
```

I looked into the RTS debugging tool, which seemed to be the recommended tool for popping open the hood for things like this in similarly posed questions on the site, but when I ran it with +RTS -xc nothing happened. I assume it's because RTS seems to require it to actually throw an exception, as opposed to the OS stepping in?

I think the major problem for myself coming from an imperative background is that the notion that the program can reach the IO statements with some sort of infinite looping procedure still going on somewhere up the logic is an alien concept. Of course, I could be completely incorrect that that's what is going on, but it's what it seems like to me. Any help you all can give (not just on this code, but also just in general with my approach to Haskell) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Could you include in your question how you are compiling your code (be sure to try with `-O2`).  2. Please include the complete, compilable, example.  The code you have posted is missing functions.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson - I was just using >>> ghc noise.hs and trying it with -O2 didn't change anything. I didn't want to post the whole code to make it readable, but I'll add it now.

Comment: Since `H(X)` is never printed it makes sense to have a look where it is calculated, i.e. `xEntropy`.  `xEntropy` calls `splitByCol` which has an obvious bug.  It never terminates!

Comment: Oy Guvalt. Wow. That didn't have anything to do with Haskell, that was just me being foolish. Thanks.

Comment: @TomEllis since you answered the question, perhaps you could post that comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since `H(X)` is never printed it makes sense to have a look where it is calculated, i.e. `xEntropy`. `xEntropy` calls `splitByCol` which has an obvious bug. It returns an infinite list!  That means `entropy` never terminates, because it attempts to call `sum` on an infinite list.